# Visual Studio cannot find relative header file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

For a while, I have been running a Visual Studio 2012 CPP project fine. However, today, all of a sudden, it has stopped being able to read any header files that are in relative directories. I cannot think what I have done to make this happen.

It seems to be an issue with Visual Studio as a whole, rather than my individual project, because I have created a new simple project and I am having the same problem. So, I have a CPP project at `C:/Projects/TestProject`. Then, I have a header file called `test_header.hpp`, which is located at `C:/Headers`. In `TestProject`'s project settings, I have added the directory `../../Headers` to `Additional Include Directories`. Then, my main functions is as follows:

```
#include "test_header.hpp"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'test.hpp': No such file or directory    c:\projects\testproject\main.cpp    1   1   TestProject
```

Any ideas on what is going on here? Is there some global Visual Studio setting that is responsible for setting up these relative directories? Just in case the relative directory was not correct, I also tried a load of others, such as `../Headers` and `../../../Headers`, but these gave the same errors.

Comment: Try adding the header file to the project, Right click solution -> Add->Existing file -> Point to your header file.

Comment: Yes -- I have just tried that, but I get the same error message...